# Get instance of child in parent class

Tags: php, oop, parent-child

Is there any way how to determine instance of child in parent class in PHP? Let's say we have this code:

```
class Parent {
    public function InstanceOfChild() {
        //What to put here to display "Child class is instance of ChildClass123"?
    }
}

class ChildClass123 extends Parent {
   //Some code here
}
```

What I need to do (if it's possible) is create method `InstanceOfChild()` which will tell me instance of child class, because a lot of classes can be child of my parent one, but I want to (let's say) log, which child call which methods. Thanks for help!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is a function **[`get_called_class()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.get-called-class.php)** what you are exactly looking for.

```
class Parent1 {
    public static function whoAmI() {
        return get_called_class();
    }
}

class Child1 extends Parent1 {}

print Child1::whoAmI(); // prints "Child1"
```

Answer (score 2):

```
class Parent {
    public function InstanceOfChild() {
        $class = get_class($this);
        return $class == 'Parent'? // check if base class
           "This class is not a child": // yes
           "Child class is instance of " . $class; // its child
    }
}
```

Note that calling:

```
$this instanceof Parent
```

Will always return true, because parent and children are all instances of class Parent.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`get_class`](http://php.net/manual/de/function.get-class.php). So, you would have to set following code:

```
echo "Child class is instance of ".get_class($childInstance);
```

(I'm not a php developer, so the syntax might be wrong)